# `open` command is not working

Tags: macos, command-line

I do have a problem with the `open` command on Mac OSX 10.11.5. It works fine when opening the finder via `open .`, however I can't seem to open Firefox:

```
$ open test.html 
[1]    78952 trace trap  open test.htm
```

`atom-cli` also gives me problems (the script `/usr/local/bin/atom` is a bit more elaborate, but it essentially boils down to `open -a "$ATOM_PATH/$ATOM_APP_NAME" -n --args --executed-from="$(pwd)" --pid=$$ --path-environment="$PATH" "$@"`):

```
$ atom .
/usr/local/bin/atom: line 115: 79282 Trace/BPT trap: 5       open -a "$ATOM_PATH/$ATOM_APP_NAME" -n --args --executed-from="$(pwd)" --pid=$$ --path-environment="$PATH" "$@"
```

I tried rebuilding the LaunchServices database with

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/LaunchServices.fra‌​mework/Support/lsregister -kill -r -domain local -domain system -domain user ; killall Dock
```

however the same errors still appear.

Any idea how to debug or fix this?

Comment: What happens when you use- `open -a Firefox test.html`?

Comment: The same thing. Does it maybe have something to do with installing the applications via `brew cask`?

Comment: I tried it with `/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Support/lsregister -kill -r -domain local -domain system -domain user ; killall Dock`, however the same error still appears.

Comment: What do you mean by "It works fine when opening the finder via `open.`"? Do you mean, in the Finder you can double click on the test.html document and it opens OK in Firefox? Does opening some things via the `open` command in Terminal work, or does nothing at all work? What does running the following in Terminal give you: `which open`? If it returns `/usr/bin/open`, what does the following return: `md5 /usr/bin/open` ? For me the checksum is `6056e93dd048a99ee5566de0f1527271`...

Comment: I mean that if I for example do `cd ~ && open .` it opens my home folder in the Finder. Some things work and some don't. `*.wav` files are opened in iTunes, `*.md` files are opened in xcode, `*.jpeg`s are opened in Preview, `*.csv` are opened in Numbers. `/usr/bin/open` is where the `open` executable is located, yes, and for the other output: `MD5 (/usr/bin/open) = 6056e93dd048a99ee5566de0f1527271`

Comment: To further elaborate: `*.zip` and `*.rar` files are extracted using Keka, which is my selected unarchiver.

Comment: `/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks‌​/LaunchServices.fram‌​ework/Support/lsregi‌​ster -kill -r -domain local -domain system -domain user ; killall Dock` works for me